# Can CSP restrict the connections of dynamically loaded script?

Tags: content-security-policy

My site is loading a third party library that loads all kinds of scripts to scrape the data from my site and send it to its own servers via XHR for analysis.  I want to make a restriction such that my page can only talk to my servers and the one third party server, and no other connections would be made.

Im wondering if CSP connect-src would do that?

For example lets say my site is x.com and the third party is y.com

If y.com loads a script that sends data to y.com it is okay but not if it sends it to z.com

I have not started to implement this yet.

Answer (score 1):

It can be controlled in Content-Security-Policy header using connect-src

```
connect-src 'self' http://y.com https://y.com;
```